# unexpected type required variable found value

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The error is: "unexpected type required variable found value", when I assign to `toSend.getNextElement()` the `firstElement`. I don't get it because `toSend.getNextElement()` isn't a value but an object.

```
public class Element{
    private int _number;
    private Element _next;
    public Element(int number) {
        _number = number;
        _next = null;
    }

    public int getNumber() {return _number;}

    public Element getNextElement() {return _next;}

    private Element longerMatch(Element eOne,Element eTwo,Element firstElement,int longest){
        if((eOne == null)||(eTwo == null)){
            Element toSend = new Element(longest);
            toSend.getNextElement() = firstElement;
            return toSend;
        }
        else if(eOne.getNumber() > eTwo.getNumber()){
            return longerMatch(eOne,eTwo.getNextElement(),null,0);
        }
        else if(eOne.getNumber() < eTwo.getNumber()){
            return longerMatch(eOne.getNextElement(),eTwo,null,0);
        }
        if(longest == 0){
            return longerMatch(eOne.getNextElement(),eTwo.getNextElement(),eOne,1);
        }
        return longerMatch(eOne.getNextElement(),eTwo.getNextElement(),firstElement,longest+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: looking it seems like you should switch it like: firstElement = toSend.getNextElement(); i dont think you can assign a value to a method

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to a value returned form a method like that. If you want to manipulate `_next`, you should a setter method for it:

```
public void setNextElement(Element next) {
    _next = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign values to variables. See the Java Tutorial and the Java Language Specification (JLS).