# I am trying to do Java program to capitalize first letter of every word of a sentence but it is giving me error

Tags: java, variables

```
public void change(int n){
    s2=(s1.substring(0.1)).toUpperCase();
  for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    if(s.charAt(i)==' '){
      c=s1.charAt(i+1);
      u=Character.toUpperCase(u);
      int n=i+1;
      s.charAt***(n)***=u;

   }
  }
}
```

The bold part gives the issue.
It is as such:-
unexpected type
required: variable
found: value

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188175/unexpected-type-required-variable-found-value

Comment: please complete the [tour], check [ask] and consider including a [mre] in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
    public static String capitalizeWords(String input) {
        String[] words = input.split("\\s+"); // Split the input sentence into words

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String word : words) {
            if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                char firstChar = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));
                result.append(firstChar).append(word.substring(1)).append(" ");
            }
        }

        // Remove the trailing space and return the result
        return result.toString().trim();
    }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain to the OP the reason for the error they are getting. And there are many duplicate questions anyway, which you must search for before answering.